# Firefox builtin pdf viewer doesnt show all characters

Tags: firefox

I open my pdf file with Firefox, and it doesnt show all characters (foreign characters arent shown). When i highlight the text and copy then paste it somewhere, it shows ALL characters.

What could be causing this and how can i fix this?

Edit: after doing more research and testing, i think it is a firefox bug. I downloaded the pdf file from firefox > opened it on chrome = everything shows. I downloaded PDF viewer addon for firefox and viewed my pdf file = everything shows. I removed the addon = nothing shows again.

Conclusion - firefox built in pdf viewer bug.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the encoding,maibe it is in UTF-8 instead of latin-1 for exemple

Comment: yes, encoding is set to UTF-8, do i need to set it to another encoding? Also the pdf works fine if i open it with other browser

Comment: when you open it with something else,is it still in utf-8?